# I got 404 error after deployed my site (Laravel with LAMP) in DigitalOcean

Tags: laravel, apache, digital-ocean, lamp

I deployed my site in DigitalOcean. It throws 404 error. The API call is working. but the front-end won't respond.

I have tried configuring the htaccess to All Granted, but it still throws 404 error.

My project address is http://134.209.103.102/

Can anyone help me on this problem?

Comment: give storage directory to 777 permission by `sudo chmod -R 777 storage`

Comment: Your dir structure ?

Comment: did you run composer install?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's late but I hope this can help the others.

I’ve done [Enabling mod_rewrite](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-rewrite-urls-with-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-ubuntu-18-04) and it works now. FYI, I only followed the Step 1 and and it works.

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access this file - http://134.209.103.102/mix-manifest.json so I guess it has nothing to do with hosting.

Check your routes (`php artisan route:list`) and `APP_URL` in the .env file.